# Require JS Refress Issue while file access from browser cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, requirejs

Am using requiredjs. After deployment to the any environment (now screenshot from local) am getting refresh issue. page is not loading properly. I have checked in network tab in firebug. its showing(below image). when the file get 200 OK (BF Cache) status, page not loading properly.

[image]

**Error:**

[image]

**After giving ctrl+f5**

all the pages are coming correctly.

[image]

some time i need to give lot of ctrl+f5 then only its working asexpected

**my requirejs config file:**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "../../../../../../../Scripts",
    //waitSecond: 0,
    //urlArgs : "q="+new Date().getTime(),
    enforcedefine: true,
    paths: {
        //RequireJS Plugins.
        'text': 'lib/requirejs/text',
        'domReady': 'lib/requirejs/domReady',
        'app': 'app',
        'noext': 'lib/requirejs/noext',

        // Shared Libraries.
        'jquery': 'lib/Kendo/jquery.min',
        'jqueryMigrate': 'lib/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min',
        'jszip': 'lib/jszip',
        'kendo': 'lib/Kendo/kendo.all.min',
        'materialize': 'lib/materialize/materialize',
        'jqueryValidate': 'jquery.validate.min',
        'jsignature': 'lib/jSignature/jSignature.min',
        'jqueryMaskedinput': 'lib/jquery/jquery.maskedinput.min',
        'jqueryMd5': 'lib/jquery/jquery.md5',
        'truckNotifier': 'Controls/serviceTruck.Notifier'
    },
    shim: {
        'app': {
            deps: ['kendo']
        },
        'kendo': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'jszip'],
        },
        'jqueryExtensions': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
        },
        'materialize': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'kendo'],
        },
        'krossRespJs': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
        },
        'jqueryMaskedinput': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
        },
        'truckUploadSelector': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
        },
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        }
    }
});
```

**app.js file:**

```
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define([
            'domReady!',
            'text',
            'noext',
            'jquery',
            'kendo',
            'jszip',
            'truckNotifier'
        ], factory);
    } else {
        // Browser globals
        factory(jQuery);
    }
}(function (domReady,text,noext,$,kendo,jszip,truckNotifier) {
    'use strict';
    var app = kendo.observable({
        // ---- PUBLIC FIELDS ----
        DATE_FORMAT: 'MM/dd/yyyy',
        DATE_MASK: '99/99/9999',
        DATE_TIME_FORMAT: 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm',
        DATE_TIME_MASK: '99/99/9999 99:99',
        PHONE_MASK: '(999) 999-9999',
        TIME_FORMAT: 'HH:mm',
        TIME_MASK: '99:99',
        $notifier: $('#notify_container'),
        router: new kendo.Router(),
        isInitialized: false,
        /** This call sets up background components of the current page.  */

        initialize: function () {
            var self = this;
            // Initialize this first so it can show loading while the rest 
            // of this module loads.

            if (!self.isInitialized) {
                $('.link-external').attr('target', '_blank');

                $('#notify_container').serviceTruckNotifier();
                self.isInitialized = true;
            }

            window.JSZip = jszip;

        },
        showPleaseWait: function (show) {
        },
        /* Pops up a notification at the top of the page. */
        notify: function (type, message) {
            var types = {
                'push': 'notifyPush',
                'info': 'notifyInfo',
                'success': 'notifySuccess',
                'error': 'notifyError',
                'warn': 'notifyWarn',
                'expired': 'notifyExpired'
            };
            this.$notifier.serviceTruckNotifier(types[type], message);
        }
    });
    app.initialize();
    return app;
}));
```

**script used in View Page:**

```
<script>
    require([
        'domReady!',
        'text',
        'noext',
        'app',
        'jquery',
        'jqueryValidate',
        'kendo',
        'truckNotifier'
    ],
    function (
        domReady,
        text,
        noext,
        app,
        $,
        jqueryValidate,
        kendo,
        truckNotifier
        ) {
        var notifier = $('#notify_container'),
            message = '@(ViewBag.Message)';
        $("#primaryTextButton").kendoButton();
        $('.all-content').removeClass('dn');
        $('.mcenter').addClass('dn');
        if (message != "") {
            notifier.serviceTruckNotifier("notifyExpired", "@C.LINK_HAS_BEEN_EXPIRED");
        }
    });
</script>
```

**HTML FILE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/Styles/all/css")
    <script src="~/Scripts/lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/config.js"></script>

</head>
<body id="@RenderSection("BodyId", false)">
    @{
        System.Reflection.Assembly web = typeof(ServiceTruck.Web.Models.ExternalLogin).Assembly;

        System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo fvi = System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(web.Location);
        string version = fvi.FileVersion;

        System.Reflection.AssemblyName webName = web.GetName();
        string myVersion = version.ToString();
        ViewBag.Version = myVersion;
    }

    @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
    <section class="container-fluid">
        @RenderBody()
    </section>
    <!-- Service Truck Layout Footer Start -->
    <footer class="copy-right">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
            <p>All rights reserved.</p>
            <p>Copyright © 2016 <a href="#">Name</a>.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
            <p>Build @myVersion</p>
            <p>Recommended Browsers: Internet Explorer 11, Firefox 48, Chrome 52</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- Service Truck Layout Footer End -->
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Intermittent errors are most of the time caused by incorrectly configuring RequireJS, or by a bad startup sequence. Right now your question does not contain enough information to allow more than guesses as to what could be wrong. Please edit your question into a [mcve]. In particular, you need to show your RequireJS configuration and how you kick off the code loading (`script` tags in the same order as in your HTML).

Comment: i have updated the question can you please check it out.

Comment: One code snippet has the heading "file". Ok, but what file is this? You're loading a lot of files. Also, my earlier comment said "you need to show [...] how you kick off the code loading **(`script` tags in the same order as in your HTML)**." (Emphasis added.) You've not show the `script` tags in the same order as your HTML. It is important. It is part of starting your application.

Comment: i have added the script what i have used in the HTML

Comment: Show *all* the script tags. You certainly are using at least one additional tag to load RequireJS.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] -- in text, not images -- as well as the text of the errors -- again, not images -- and what should be happening.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is definitely wrong with your configuration is the `shim` for `app`:

```
    'app': {
        deps: ['kendo']
    },
```

Your `app` module is an AMD module: it calls `define`. So you cannot use a `shim` for it. Setting a `shim` for a module that cannot benefit from one can lead to undefined behavior.

I've run experiments with this at times and got inconsistent results from one version of RequireJS to the next. The point is that setting a `shim` for an AMD module has no defined semantics.

Comment: I have removed that dependency for 'app'. still am facing the same problem